# Azure VPN TTL expired in transit

Tags: vpn, azure, gateway, azure-networking

I have an Azure VPN connected to our Azure VLAN.

If we connect to the VPN from some laptops, it works fine, they can access everything, browse to internal sites, ping the VM's on the VLAN etc..

But if the same users connect, from certain laptops (all of which run Windows 10), they connect successfully, but cannot access anything, if they try and ping a VM they get:

TTL expired in transit

Now the laptop that has most recently had this issue, is a clean Windows 10 install.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

If we do a tracert on the broken laptop, it never reaches the VM, but on a good laptop it does.

It doesn't sound like a loop issue because the way that the problem is intermittent depending on which laptop is used

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be that 2 routes were not being added on the client machine by the VPN when connecting, adding the route manually was a workaround.
Downloading the latest VPN client from Azure Portal provided a perm solution, as the new VPN Client added all routes as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a routing loop, but can't give a good diagnostic without further data such as:

- Working machine's routing table before connecting to the VPN
- Working machine's routing table after connecting to the VPN
- Non-working machine's routing table before connecting to the VPN
- Non-working machine's routing table after connecting to the VPN

My educated guess is the non-working machines do not have the routes pointing to the Azure VNet through the VPN tunnel after connecting, so traffic gets routed inside your corporate network. This is either due to these machines being on a different network with maybe overlapping routes or these machines having different permissions that prevent the configuration of the routes after installing the P2S package generated by Azure for the tunnel, in which case you'd like to check the logs for that.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that some laptops on Azure VPN can access everything, but other laptops on Azure VPN  cannot.  When you ping the VM from the broken laptops, you receive the error message "TTL Expired in Transit".

First of all, this TTL Expired in Transit is an ICMP reply which has nothing to do with Windows 10. It tells the Time To Live value set on the ping packets expire before reaching the VM.

My too first guess is a possible routing loop as suggested by Pedro Perez.  But you believe it is not due to a routing loop. We can check it by increasing the TTL value of the ping command.

I suggest you set a reasonably higher TTL value when you ping the VM address. You can do it by using the -i parameter.

For example, here I set the TTL value as 300 when I ping Google.

ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) -i 300

If you still receive a TTL expired in transit message, I suggest you check the routing table for a loop. If increasing the TTL value fixed your problem, I suggest you change the default TTL value on your broken laptops.

Ref  https://www.corenetworkz.com/2011/05/ttl-expired-in-transit-reason-and.html